# Include many records on one report with different values

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm attempting to create a report in Access 2016 that resembles a bank deposit slip [image: bank deposit slip,] however I've been unable to find any way to display anything more than one record per report.

I have a query "Transactions" that sorts everything out and gives a datasheet with all the transactions to be used, the goal is to populate the report with up to around 12 different values from different transactions.

Is this even possible within access? My only thought thus far is to create a table with individual columns for each transaction, but that just seems messy.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you using the Report Wizard to create the report? If so, are you selecting the "Justified" layout?

Comment: This is not a programming question, it is a design issue. If you want each transaction to be an item listed on deposit slip, this should be a fairly simple report with page header/footer. Edit question to show sample data, desired output, attempted query.